# How to test if console.error fired in jasmin

Tags: angular, jasmine

I have an error handling service that prints console.error statements that differ depending on what's passed in (ex. http error vs non-http error).

Is there any way to test for the existance of console.error statements that are outputted from the service?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use spies for this:

```
spyOn(console, 'error');

// execute your tests

expect(console.error).toHaveBeenCalledWith("your expected message");
```